# Add custom menu action to Caja file manager

Tags: mate-desktop, caja

There should be a tool to create such actions in Caja (default file manager in Mate desktop environment), installed with

```
sudo apt install caja-actions
```

But it doesn't seem to work, as indicated [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-enable-caja-custom-actions-on-ubuntu-mate-16-04-mate-1-12-1/15140).

In my case, this tool is in the start menu, but it doesn't launch (Mint Mate 18.3, based on Ubuntu 16.04).

How to create such actions manually?

---

This is posted in order to provide an answer.

Comment: **If the question above seems stupid** -  I don't wanna die stupid: Please add a comment saying why the down-vote - in order to show what can be fixed or at least  to tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in the same way as for Nautilus and PCManFM, after installing `caja-actions` and ensuring it is selected in Caja - Preferences - Extensions.

[image]

Create the folder `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions`.

With `xed` as text manager - adding an action to open a file as text, open a terminal and run

```
xed ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/open_as_text.desktop
```

with these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Open as text
Name=Open as text
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=xed

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
MimeTypes=all/all;
Exec=xed %f
Name=Open as text
```

Save and restart Caja.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After installing caja-actions, reboot the pc, then run

```
$ caja-actions-config-tool
```

or open it from the menu.